# Why rotate the Falcon 9 2nd stage after deployment?

Tags: rockets, spacex, falcon-9, orbital-maneuver, upper-stage

Towards the end of the [JCSAT-14 live webcast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0bMeDj76ig), after the satellite was deployed, we could see small thrusters firing on the second stage, starting to rotate it:

[image]

The webcast ended shortly afterwards, with (I believe) no explanation of what was happening<sup>1</sup>, so I'm wondering what the purpose of this was.  Perhaps to get ready for an engine relight to re-test that capability / deorbit the second stage more quickly?

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that before the deployment, they did mention rotating the stage, but that was to stabilise it before deployment.  I believe this later rotation is unrelated.

Answer (score 6):

At the end of the webcast, they mention the last step is to safe the spacecraft. I suspect all they were doing was getting rid of the remaining fuel on the spacecraft. Rotating it might lead to a slightly quicker reentry as it will be more likely to be broadside for longer to the atmosphere, increasing drag, but I think that is a secondary concern.

Comment: So are you saying that it wasn't a thruster per se, rather they were actively venting the remaining fuel?  Does that explain why it seemed to "build up" a bit on the thruster (if you watch it, you can see it "icing" up around the nozzle) - I wouldn't expect a normal thruster to ice up in this fashion (almost submitted another question about that)

Comment: It's obviously some kind of a thruster. That would be a valid second question to ask. I suspect it's a cold gas thruster, which is basically compressed air, and will cool for the same reason a can of compressed air will cool when you spray it, but I'd have to do some more research. It could also be venting the super cool fuel, which would have a similar effect.

Comment: Right, that makes sense.  I'll go re-get my screengrabs of the buildup...

Comment: Disagreed with 'that is obviously some kind of a thruster.' It's shown to leak continuously through almost all Falcon orbital operations, plenty of armchair guesses that it's a LOX vent from MVac chilldown, and I'm pretty sure it's even been referenced in webcasts as a 'vent' because it's a frequent point of interest as it grows and sheds solid oxygen ice. It likely even has a symmetrical twin on the far side to ensure it's a nonpropulsive vent - this can be guessed from best practice plus the symmetrical vent hoses in the interstage.

Answer (score 4):

The thing circled in the photo is LOX vent. The puffy white object is solid oxygen.  It was described at [T+1.05:25 in the Iridium-6/GRACE-FO webcast](https://youtu.be/I_0GgKfwCSk?t=1h21m20s). As such, it's not intended to rotate the spacecraft.

Answer (score 2):

Likely it was to aim the stage for an orbital change either to reenter sooner, or a parking orbit much higher and out of the way. Do not want to leave clutter around GEO/GTO orbits.

Comment: Considering it was GTO, I'm fairly confident it wasn't a parking orbit. And it wouldn't make that much sense to perform a reentry maneuver so low in the orbit. Hmmm...